# Scan URLs in CSV file and add column TRUE/FALSE once websites are active/not active

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and currently trying to find a way to scan through all the URLs in my CSV file in order to find if a website has specific string displayed (in my case I need to check for multiple strings: 'Unavailable', 'Coming soon' and 'Temporarily closed').

CSV file structure:

```
id    website
1    https://www.rainfordsolutions.com/new-online-shop-coming-soon
2    https://www.arrey-fashion.com/a-nice-entry/
3    https://google.com
...
```

I think that I will need some sort of a loop through my website URLs first, then for each website another loop to see if the keywords I'm looking for are there or not, and finally write results to my CSV file where: TRUE if keywords were not found (website active), FALSE if any of my keywords have been found (website not active). I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I started with pandas and urlllib.request, but I know there is also beautiful soup and request library. Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/file/with/urls.csv')
for v in df['website']:
with urllib.request.urlopen(v) as url:


df['active'] = 

df.to_csv('path/to/my/output/urls_and_flag.csv', index=False)
```

Desired output urls_and_flag.csv:

```
id    website                                                           active
1    https://www.rainfordsolutions.com/new-online-shop-coming-soon      FALSE
2    https://www.arrey-fashion.com/a-nice-entry/                        FALSE
3    https://google.com                                                 TRUE
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can asynchronously execute a function using something like `asyncio` and wait for the results. In your function use [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) to look for your text or whatever. Then write the results to the csv file :

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
import re

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

urls = df.T.values.tolist()[1]
results = {}

async def scrape(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        data = {
            "help": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("^help$", re.I)),
            "search": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("^search$", re.I))
        }
        results[url] = data
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        results[url] = { "help": [], "search": []}

async def main():
    await asyncio.wait([scrape(url) for url in urls])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()

helpList= []
searchList = []
for url in urls:
    helpList.append("x" if len(results[url]["help"]) > 0 else "")
    searchList.append("x" if len(results[url]["search"]) > 0 else "")

df["help"] = pd.DataFrame(helpList, columns=['help'])
df["search"] = pd.DataFrame(searchList, columns=['search'])

print(df)

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: it seems that I'm getting a `KeyError: 'https://testesttest.one'` when domain doesn't exist. Would you know how to skip and flag those cases in the loop separately? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Baobab1988 I've added a try except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: to process that case

Comment: I tested the above code and now it skips all the websites that are down but throws the following error on the ones that don't have keywords listed on them: `helpList.append("x" if len(results[url]["help"]) > 0 else "") KeyError: 'https://example.com'` Would there be a way to first scan and flag websites as active/not active and then eliminate them from the scan the not active ones as a second step, instead of looping with exception? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Baobab1988 I can't reproduce the issue, I've just run the script on csv containing site down, site with keyword and site without it though

Comment: I know where I made a mistake... I modified the code for keywords from `"^help$"` to `"\W*((?i)help(?-i))\W*"` - but i think this wasn't necessary as your code captures all possible hits, right?. Would it also get double words? I'm also trying to get a column ["url_status"] with `x` as a value in my output csv file for websites which have status 404 or 403 or any other issues that prevent reaching the server. Would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: @Baobab1988 use `r.status_code` to get the status code. Also for testing regex I'd recommend to go to https://regex101.com/ and choose python